# directive's scope inside ng-repeat angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to understand directive's scope inside ng-repeat, still wondering if it comes from ng-repeat but it looks like.
Here is my code

**directive.js**

```
myApp.directive('dirSample', function () {
  return {
    template: '<input type="text" ng-model="name" />',
    replace: true,
    restrict: 'AE'
  }
});
```

**mainController.js**

```
angular.controller('mainController',function($scope){
    $scope.name = 'name'
});
```

**index.htm**

```
<div ng-repeat="i in [1, 2, 3, 4]">
   <dir-sample></dir-sample>
</div>

<dir-sample></dir-sample>
<dir-sample></dir-sample>
```

When i make a change in one of the last two directives (which are not inside ng-repeat) it works well, changes on one are reflected on the other.

**Problem :**

1 - if i change an input value of a directive generated by ng-repeat , changes are not reflected anywhere else.
2 - if i change value of input on one of the two last directives , the directives inside ng-repeat change too, but if touch ( change input value ) of any directive , changes will not be reflected on that directive but will keep being reflected on the other directives.

Can someone please explain why the scope has that behavior ?

Thanks.

Comment: ngRepeat creates new scope per iteration.

Comment: Then why changes on the last two directives are reflected on those inside ngRepeat until i touch them?

Comment: You need to read (a lot, but it is important if you want to understand JS better) about how prototypical inheritance work. Scope inheritance in Angular is base on good old JS prototypes. As I said ngRepeat creates new scope. It means that primitive properties will shadow outer scope properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Binding primitives is tricky, as is explained here: [Understanding scopes](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes). It has to with how Javascript works. Your 'name' variable will get shadowed once it is altered within the ng-repeat block. The suggested fix (from the link above):

> This issue with primitives can be easily avoided by following the
>   "best practice" of always have a '.' in your ng-models

They also provide a link to a video explaining exactly this problem: [AngularJS MTV Meetup](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZhfUv0spHCY&feature=youtu.be&t=30m)

So a fix looks like this:

```
app.controller('mainController',function($scope){
    $scope.attr= {}
    $scope.attr.name = 'name'
});

app.directive('dirSample', function () {
  return {
    template: '<input type="text" ng-model="attr.name" />',
    replace: true,
    restrict: 'AE'
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you. Looks like i have quite few concepts to catch on ...
Edit : The link you provided explains very well the concept. THANKS AGAIN .

Comment: Another fix would be to use Object.define property to define getter and setter for name. This prevents shadowing as well and keeps the code more readable (my opinion).